# WPF SQL Distributed Data Model with LINQ and SQL Express

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am developing an application in C#/WPF that requires a distributed data model, as it will have both online and offline access.

My current thoughts are to develop the first version of the application against SQL Server express and LINQ to SQL. Then use the schema to create a SQL Express Compact DB (and modify the connection string) for distribution.

Once that version is how I like it, I will add the "distributededness" to the application by creating a web service that the application syncs its local database with.

My questions are: is this a good approach? And will I run into problems by turning my reference to a "real" SQL server into a reference to a local self-contained SQL database file? I had issues trying to create LINQ to SQL with a compact DB reference, but I can't see how it is different then a reference to a "real" server.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that SQL Server Compact Edition is missing a few features when compared to SQL Server Express? I learned that the hard way once in a situation like this. [http://tinyurl.com/2antqx]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I am considering this:

http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/

Then use LINQ to SQLITE for my application.

Are there any comments on this approach?